# Creating a treemap without libraries

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, treemap

I'm working on creating a treemap without libraries for a project, but I'm facing some difficulties with this, arranging blocks in a parent block and calculating the height and width like some libraries do. It would be great if you could take a look at my code and share your ideas or tips. Here is a link to my code: my code [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-elion-mjt8t5)

I would be very grateful for any help and feedback!

I expect the blocks to be laid out like this, but I don’t understand how to do it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).